# Set timezone in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I have a script that we use to add new employees to our Active directory domain and groups. We are trying to see if there is a way that we can also add timezone with the script but I am not find anything helpful on how to do this.

We currently are using the **dsadd** commands to add users but I am not seeing that there is an option to add timezones with it. We did try it anyways to see if it might work and we did get errors saying it was an unknown option.

I am not sure what additional information might be needed. Any questions or suggestions please let me know.

Comment: You... want to add a timezone to your... users? That's not really how time zones work... Timezones apply to physical locations, not users, or user groups, or scripts.  Perhaps you should clarify what, specifically, it is you're trying to do here.

Comment: It is for our users. We have sales people that live across the country and in our CRM with syncs with our AD users it is reading our default timezone. So their calendars are not showing them the right times for the meetings. If they try to change it themselves it gets changed back the next time the sync with AD happens.

Comment: A timezone cannot be applied to a user any more than a timezone can be applied to a person. You can set a timezone on a user's computer, however.

Comment: timezone isn't an AD user attribute that I'm aware of. As @HopelessN00b stated, timezones are applied to computers, not users. You should make sure that each users computer timezone is set correctly and if the CRM application doesn't work properly then you should take that up with the CRM vendor.

Comment: @solutionary: How are your users running the CRM application?  Is it on a terminal server?  A windows application on their desktop? A web-based application?

Comment: It is Web-based. In AD if you look at the Attribute Editor in the user's properties there is an option for the TimeZone for each user.

Answer (score 1):

Your CRM application is likely reading the users location from AD.  Ensure the address attributes are correct.